# What is the most simple way to play a continuous but dynamic animation? Game-engine vs. animation?

Tags: animation, game-engine

I'm relatively new to Blender (or more accurately returning after a long hiatus).

I want to render a fairly simple animation continuously, the movement of the animation is based on an external process (a camera is following actions in the real world, and a process external to blender will decide the settings for the blender model and write them to a file). I'm using an existing model and simply updating a few properties of the model continuously.

Reading the values from the file and updating the blender model using python should be easy.

> However, I'm unclear whether I'm better off treating this as an animation, or as a game in Blender? Which will be easier to configure and why?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a file? This can became problematic, when the file gets written at the same time. When you want real time, it might be better to use a network connection. The overall design would be the same: define a protocol, establish a formatter (to send data) and a parser (to receive data).

Comment: It'll be a named pipe, that part I'm quite comfortable coding. It's the blender part I'm less confident in. :)  I've been looking into the game engine, and it seems like the right answer will be to run it as a game.